# OneNote ScreenCapture Knockoff in Visual Studio 2008/2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, onenote

Everyone at our company has Microsoft Office, and there are a few copies that have more features than others.

One feature that Engineering wants to have installed on every Engineer's PC is [OneNote's ability to do a partial screen capture](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/use-screen-clippings-to-capture-information-quickly-HA010212472.aspx) simply by pressing Win+S. The screen turns cloudy, the mouse turns to a cross hair, the user drags a region that becomes un-cloudy as he drags, and when he stops dragging the image displays in a viewer (unsaved, and still on the clipboard).

I must confess, I knew nothing about this feature until today. In fact, I don't even have OneNote on my PC.

What would be the best way to go about creating a screen capturing tool like the one used in OneNote? I've already developed a very robust screen capturing tool for use in my WinForm applications, but it looks like OneNote is done in something like SilverLight or WPF. I've never gotten into either.

Anyway, it is too expensive to upgrade every Engineer's version of MS Office just for this one little feature of OneNote.

What would be the best way to approach a little tool like this? Has someone made an example like it already? What should I develop this with?

Comment: Tell them to download Greenshot.

Comment: That looks pretty cool. It's even open source! Sweeeeeeeeeet!

Comment: there's also http://www.windowclippings.com/ and http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/. You probably don't need to develop your own screenshot program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) open source application supports partial screen capture. I believe that by default after the region is captured it is open in a custom image editor that supports simple editing operation like adding labels and highlights, but I believe it can be configured to only copy the region to clipboard.